# The colour of pixels of the image are incorrect

Tags: c#, imaging

I'm trying to compare 2 images with a comparison function called SAD (sum of square differences), I take a block from each image, and I convert the pixels to grayscale and I do the comparison.
but the problem is that if I compare two identical blocks, the result of sad isn't 0 (so there is a difference). I checked with multiple messageboxes and then I saw that the program returns incorrect colors for pixels: for example, black pixel=255 instead of 0.

here the code of my comparison function:

```
 public double SAD(bloc Bc, bloc Br)
    {
        double sad = 0;
        {
            BitmapData bmp = image1.LockBits(new Rectangle(Bc.x, Bc.y, taille_bloc, taille_bloc), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
            BitmapData bmp2 = image2.LockBits(new Rectangle(Br.x, Br.y, taille_bloc, taille_bloc), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
            IntPtr ptr2 = bmp2.Scan0;
            IntPtr ptr = bmp.Scan0;
            int bytes = bmp.Width * bmp.Height * 3;
            double gris1, gris2;
            byte[] rgb = new byte[bytes];
            byte[] rgb2 = new byte[bytes];
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgb, 0, bytes);
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr2, rgb2, 0, bytes);
            for (int i = 0; i < rgb.Length; i += 3)
            {

                 gris1 = rgb[i] * 0.2989 + rgb[i+1] * 0.5870 + rgb[i+2] * 0.1140;
                 gris2 = rgb2[i] * 0.2989 + rgb2[i + 1] * 0.5870 + rgb2[i + 2] *  0.1140;

                sad = sad + Math.Abs(gris2 - gris1);

            }
            image2.UnlockBits(bmp2);

            image1.UnlockBits(bmp);
        }

        return sad;

    }
```

If I didn't be clear in my explanation please tell me so I will reformulate

thank you very much in advance for your help :)

Comment: Are you certain the images are identical? If you are comparing identical images, you should get identical results for identical calculations. Perhaps abstract away the common parts to a function and call that for each image/pixel?

Comment: Can you provide a short, self contained, compilable example (see http://sscce.org/) so we can run it quickly and try to help you. The one you have provided contains missing types and variables.

Comment: First of all, I do not see this as calculating a sum of square differences. It looks like it is calculating a sum of differences.

Comment: Secondly, since you are computing differences, you probably do not need to apply the correction factors for human eye color perception.

Comment: Thirdly, are you sure that conversion to grayscale is necessary? I hope you understand that this may, in theory, classify two images as identical even though they may differ in coloring. In any case, even if conversion to grayscale is needed, you should have isolated that within a completely different function, which you would have tested to make sure it works, so as to minimize the things that can go wrong in the code that we are looking at.

Comment: Finally, it is not clear at all what you mean by "I checked with multiple messageboxes". What on earth do messageboxes have to do with the problem at hand?  And yes, please do what Abbas asked.

Comment: yes images are identical
and it sum of absolute differences (I made an error while typing)
it is not necessary to convert to grayscale but it will avoid to use the structure RGB and calculate 3 times. for the messages boxes, it has nothing to do with the problem, it was just a detail. thanks

Answer (score 1):

One possible problem is that your number of bytes calculation is wrong. You have:

```
int bytes = bmp.Width * bmp.Height * 3;
```

But bitmaps are padded, typically to a 4-byte boundary. You need to use

```
int bytes = bmp.Stride * bmp.Height;
```

`Stride` is the number of bytes it takes to represent a scan line. For a 24-bit image, that will be equal to `3 * bmp.Width` PLUS the number of bytes required for padding (which might be zero).

To index the array, then, you go line by line, and ignore the padding bytes. You have to initialize your index at the beginning of each row.

```
for (int row = 0; row < bmp.Height; ++row)
{
    int i = row * bmp.Stride;
    for (int p = 0; p < bmp.Width; ++p)
    {
        // do comparisons with rgb[i], rgb[i+1], rgb[i+2]
        i += 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer,if I use bmp.Stride, how I will acces my RGB values? (in my code I'm advancing by 3 in every iteration, if I don't know how many colums are there in my table, I won't know where the RGB values are stored)

Comment: sorry, the comment I posted previously here was wrong, I removed it. Instead of looping for each byte of bitmap data, you need to loop for each row (y) and within that loop you need another loop for each column (x). The location of a pixel is at rgb[(y * bmp.Stride) + (x * 3) + c] where c = 0, 1 or 2 for R, G or B. Unless, of course, your bitmap uses 4 bytes per pixel, in which case you need to adjust accordingly.